# multiplication limit of integers for GMP library

Tags: c, integer, multiplication, gmp, iec10967

I was attempting to multiply two very large `mpz_t`s together, each of `2^(10*2^22) bits`, using the `mpz_mul` function in the GMP library.

There was no segmentation fault, and the multiplication managed to go through. However, when I output the result of the multiplication to a file, all I observed is a string of trailing zeros.

Is there any way I can overcome this limitation?

Comment: How are you printing to a file? You are using gmp functions only, right?? It will be better if you could post the code!!!

Comment: I am just using gmp_fprintf to output the results to a file in GMP. @Arpit

Comment: I can't tell you like this unless you post the code. Try printing it on console or try other values. Debug it.

Comment: Hang on, *how* many bits? 2^(10*2^22) is 2^41943040. I hope that's not how many bits you have. (More realistically, I would guess you have two 42MBit numbers...)

Comment: What do you mean, trailing zeroes? If there's a 1 anywhere, then the number is just divisible by a large power of 2.

Answer (score -1):

How about [bn](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html) lib (this library performs arithmetic operations on integers of arbitrary size) ?! You can use bn library and convert the result to GMP's value.